# Filters and relationships data from a display to another within the same view

Tags: blocks, views

Hi everybody,

I've been freshly introduced to Drupal and I'm having my first "serious" issue with contextual filters and relationships. Here is the context :

- I have a "process" content type and several contents (processes)based on it
- Some processes (contents) have an field, called "sub-process", which is an entity reference to processes
- I made a grid page view showing every process and a bloxk view showing every "sub-process"
- In every cell of the grid, there is one process and I want to display the sub-processes attached to it.
- I can display the name of every process's sub-process through the "sub-process" field, but I would like to display other properties of these subprocesses.
- To do so, I used the Views Field View module and a Global : view field. The problem is that it shoes all the subprocesses in all the cells of the gris except the right ones.

Any idea how to proceed ?

Answer (score 2):

On your "subprocess" display, you need to add a relationship to the process that is referencing that subprocess. Then add a contextual filter of the process id using the relationship you created. Finally, add a field "Id" in the "process" display and pass the process id as contextual filter in the global view field (check the replacing patterns).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should consider https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view .  It is basically a subquery.  make sure you have views caching enabled as these can get complex quickly.